# Oracle-Insert Comma separated string values into Table --

Tags: oracle

Trying to insert an entire row which is accepted by procedure input parameter  as comma separated string `'THIS,IS,AN,Example,null,STRING'` into table

Here is what I have tried:

```
DECLARE
  I_NPUT VARCHAR2(4000) := 'THIS,IS,AN,Example,null,STRING# This , is ,an,another,ex,null#'The,list,goes,on,on,null'';
  L_COUNT BINARY_INTEGER;
  L_ARRAY DBMS_UTILITY.LNAME_ARRAY;
BEGIN
  DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE(LIST => REGEXP_REPLACE(I_NPUT, '(^|,)', '\1x'), TABLEN => L_COUNT, TAB => L_ARRAY);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_COUNT);
  FOR I IN 1 .. L_COUNT
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Element ' || TO_CHAR(I) || ' of array contains: ' || SUBSTR(L_ARRAY(I), 2));
    INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
      (SUBSTR(L_ARRAY(I), 2)
      );
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The return needs to be:

```
COL_1    COL_2   COL_3  COL_4   COL_5  COL_6
-----------------------------------------------
THIS     IS      AN     Example null   STRING
```

Comment: How about you show us what you tried..? We're not here to write software for you, we're here to help you with problems you can't figure out.

Comment: Typically, each element in the list goes into a single varchar2 column.  You have written this so that you are attempting to insert each element in its own column (not very workable if you do not know how many elements are in your list). Do you really need all elements to go into one record? Do you really know the number of elements in your list?

Comment: if my string input is this 'THIS,IS,AN,Example,null,STRING# This , is ,an,another,ex,null#'The,list,goes,on,on,null' the row is distinguished by # it need to insert into table row wise.

Answer (score 1):

```
sss := replace(p_string,',',''',''');
sss := regexp_replace(sss, '''null''','null');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO your_table (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, COL_6) 
VALUES (''' ||sss|| ''')';
```

Here p_string - your input string